# Can I use <inheritdoc cref> to reference the XML summary of another variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation, inheritdoc

When I'm writing functions for my project, and more specifically, their XML documentation comments, I find myself repeating the comments for a specific parameter often. This leads to misleading documentation sometimes (as copy pasting usually does...).

This is a simple example I thought of, which represents the real problem.

```
/// <summary>
/// The number that should be doubled
/// </summary>
private static float myNumber = 10f;

/// <summary>
/// Multiplies a number by 2
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number"><inheritdoc cref="myNumber"/></param>
/// <returns>The number multiplied by 2</returns>
private static float MultiplyByTwo(float number)
{
    return number * 2f;
}
```

In this line `/// <param name="number"><inheritdoc cref="myNumber"/></param>`, I would like to have the text "The number that should be doubled", but it's not showing up. Maybe I don't understand the use of inheritdoc completely.

What I mean by showing up is this. Visual Studio should show the documentation of `number` in that box:

[image: visual studio info box not showing the documentation when hovering over the function]

This is what it should look like (without copy pasting the text):

[image: visual studio info box showing the documentation when hovering over the function]

So, is there a way to reference a different variable in XML documentation comments?

Comment: `<inheritdoc>` can only inherit XML comments from base classes, interfaces, and similar methods.

Comment: Ah, that’s what I feared. So there’s no other way than just copy pasteing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Visual Studio 16.8.4 I'm able to use `<inheritdoc>`'s `path` attribute to do this.

```
/// <summary>
/// The number that should be doubled
/// </summary>
private static float myNumber = 10f;
        
/// <summary>
/// Multiplies a number by 2
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number"><inheritdoc cref="myNumber" path="/summary"/></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static float MultiplyByTwo(float number)
{
    return number * 2f;
}
```

In the `path` attribute, `/` selects the 'root' node and then `summary` is the node to select within that node.

Result:

[image]

The `path` attribute uses XPath syntax, which you can [find more about here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

You can use it to do some great stuff if you're careful; I regularly use it when implementing the `Try[...]` pattern.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// This throws!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param1">This is a parameter.</param>
/// <param name="param2">This is another parameter!</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
public string ExampleThatCanThrow(int param1, float param2)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

/// <summary>
/// This never throws!
/// </summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="ExampleThatCanThrow(int, float)" path="/*[not(self::exception)]"/>
public bool TryExample(int param1, float param2, out string? result)
{
    result = "No throwing here!";
    return true;
}
```

Normally when using `<inheritdoc>` for the `TryExample` method in this way, it would show that it could throw `InvalidOperationException`. Using the `path` attribute, I've filtered it so only the nodes that don't match the name of `exception` will be inherited.

`/`: Matches the root node.

`*`: Matches any child node.

`[` and `]`: Matches any node that meets the conditions of the contained predicate.

`not()`: Matches any node that doesn't meet the conditions of the expression within the parentheses.

`self::exception`: Matches the current node if it has the name of `exception`.

This results in the below:

[image]
[image]

In addition, you can use this functionality to more easily show the exceptions that can be thrown by a method without typing them out explicitly:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validates a file in some way.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">A full path to the file to be validated.</param>
/// <inheritdoc cref="File.OpenRead(string)" path="/exception"/>
private static void ValidateFile(string filePath)
{
    using FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    // Validation code...
}
```

This above use of `<inheritdoc>` will cause the tooltip on the method to show that it can throw all of the exceptions that the `System.IO.File.OpenRead` method can throw. Just be careful that you ensure necessary validation exceptions are actually thrown and accounted for.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with ReSharper.